# Is pseudocode for insertion sorting correct?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I try to implement in Python the next pseudocode (from [Russian page for insertion sorting](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)):

```
for i = 2, 3, ..., n:  
    key := A[i]
    j := i - 1
    while j >= 1 and A[j] > key:
        A[j+1] := A[j]
        j := j - 1
    A[j+1] := key
```

I have a error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insertion.py", line 6, in test_sort
    self.assertEqual( sort( [ 5, 2, 6, 3, 7 ] ), [ 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 ] )
  File "insertion.py", line 12, in sort
    key = a[ i ]
IndexError: list index out of range

My code of the sort() is:

```
def sort( a ):
    len_a = len( a )
    len_a_plus_1 = len_a + 1
    for i in range( 2, len_a_plus_1 ):
        key = a[ i ]
        j = i - 1

        while j >= 1 and a[ j ] > key:
            a[ j + 1 ] = a[ j ]
            j -= 1
        a[ j + 1 ] = key

    return a
```

If I change arguments for the range() call:

```
for i in range( 2, len_a )
```

... then I get an incorrect result:

```
[5, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

Is my code wrong or is algorythm in the [article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) innacurate?

**Update**.

I changed the code (with 0-indexed Python principle), but it does not work properly:

```
def sort( a ):
    len_a = len( a )
    for i in range( 1, len_a ):
        key = a[ i ]
        j = i - 1

        while j and a[ j ] > key:
            a[ j + 1 ] = a[ j ]
            j -= 1
        a[ j + 1 ] = key

    return a
```

Input: [ 5, 2, 6, 3, 7 ]
Output: [5, 2, 3, 6, 7]

**The resolution**.

We found a solution:

```
while j and a[ j ] > key
```

shoud be

```
while j >= 0 and a[ j ] > key
```

Comment: Please check Python code conventions: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[5, 2]` does not work either. If you just check `while j (>0)` you won't ever move the first item.
I think this works

```
while j >= 0 and a[ j ] > key:
```

Answer (score 2):

Python uses 0-based indexing, making `a[len(a)]` out of range. The pseudo-code uses 1-based indexing.

You need to decrease *both* your indices by one:

```
len_a = len(a)
for i in range(1, len_a):
```

and

```
while j >= 0 and a[j] > key:
```

Comment: Thank you. I do that but my test still does not pass. The result is [5, 2, 3, 6, 7], should be [2, 3, 5, 6, 7].

Comment: --- should be `while j >= 0 and a[j] > key:`